# How to get all values of check boxes on button click asp.net

Tags: c#

I have 10 check boxes populated using repeater

I want to grab all check boxes values which are checked on asp.net button click event in c#

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puesdo codeish

checkedBoxes as new list(of checkbox)

```
for each item as repeater in repeater.items

 checkbox = (CheckBox)item.findcontrol("checkboxid")

 if checkbox.checked
  checkedBoxes.add(checkbox)
 end if

end for
```