# How to get checkboxid which is placed inside the repeater control from the codebehind side?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

Let us assume sample.aspx is a page
this page contails the following Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr><td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# container.dataitem("CUISINENAME")%>' />
  </td></tr>    
 </ItemTemplate>                       
</asp:Repeater>
```

My question is "while clicking the submit button in server side, 
i have to find the checkboxid which is placed inside the Repeater control. 
Any one help me Regarding this ?

Answer (score 1):

[How to get all values of check boxes on button click asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727808/how-to-get-all-values-of-check-boxes-on-button-click-asp-net/4727840#4727840)